# start workflow programmatically in liferay

Tags: liferay, workflow, activiti

I integrated activiti and liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4. I have created a simple workflow in activiti-explorer to ask for tea.

```
<process id="hello" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="start" activiti:initiator="initiator"></startEvent>
    <userTask id="usertask" name="H_usertask" activiti:assignee="kermit">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:formProperty id="consult" name="Do u want tea ??" type="enum">
          <activiti:value id="yes" name="yes"></activiti:value>
          <activiti:value id="no" name="no"></activiti:value>
        </activiti:formProperty>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <endEvent id="end"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="start" targetRef="usertask"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="usertask" targetRef="end"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
```

I deployed it into liferay. How i can start this workflow in liferay.
Please give some solution for this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: By integrating, what do you mean really, since you can hit it both from REST or by the library api. Do you mean the library api? Do you see the activiti tables are being created?

Comment: I mean that i changed the liferay's default workfow engine "kaleo-web" with "activiti-web" which i downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9hpjh8pfq5c4li/activiti-web-6.2.0.14.war . I have a workflow definition which i place above. I want to start this workflow definition in liferay. Activiti tables are created in same database which i defined for liferay-portal.